# how to check if my cpanel server has tomcat installed on it

Tags: java, spring, servlets, cpanel

I have a cPanel want to deploy java application on it, but i would like to check if Tomcat server installed on it or not and what version and edit files of it ?

where can i find it from cPanel control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have linux based server. You can check by running command:

```
sh /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/version.sh
```

It will output something similar:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Server built:   time here
Server number:  7.0.42.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-042stab084.26
Architecture:   processor
JVM Version:    1.7.0_21-b11
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

**Another way:**
The best way to check is to upload a JSP file to print out some info like in this example: bestdesigns.co.in/blog/check-jsp-tomcat-version

Save this code into a file called `tomcat_version.jsp`:

```
    Tomcat Version : <%= application.getServerInfo() %><br>    
    Servlet Specification Version : 
<%= application.getMajorVersion() %>.<%= application.getMinorVersion() %> <br>    
    JSP version :
<%=JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getEngineInfo().getSpecificationVersion() %><br>
```

When you access, http://example.com/tomcat_version.jsp, the output should look similar if apache installed:

```
Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/5.5.25
Servlet Specification Version : 2.4
JSP version: 2.0
```

Comment: what this error means ?
HTTP Status 404 - /~mysite/tomcat_version.jsp
**description The requested resource is not available.**

Comment: Your jsp file must be under web-content directory.

Comment: you mean public_html folder  ?

Comment: don't you have ssh access ?

Answer (score 0):

You can by trying to start / stop tomcat, to see if it responds to any:

To start Tomcat :

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat  start
```

To stop Tomcat :

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat   stop
```

Done

Another way:

Check if any of the following gives you some valid path.

```
echo "$CATALINA_HOME"

echo "$TOMCAT_HOME"
```

Comment: Your file: /tomcat_version.jsp must be in webapps/foo/WEB-INF